# Should I use "is swearing" or "are swearing" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Half of the words that come out of your mouth is/are swearing.

Should it be is or are? And why?

I searched for [out of your mouth is swearing](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=t0YKW6DkNMW80gTFva_QAw&q=%22out%20of%20your%20mouth%20is%20swearing%22&oq=%22out%20of%20your%20mouth%20is%20swearing%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1193.2676.0.2789.8.6.1.0.0.0.93.515.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.lhgWqEwPWqg). It only returned one Google result, so I'm not very confident about the "answer".

Comment: The problem with your question is that **words** are not swearing. They may be curses, profanities, oaths and the like. Swearing, whether a formal act in court or uttering foul language, is a human activity. But **half the words are.....*

Comment: @RonaldSole I think that we all agree that words don't swear but OP is talking about swearing [noun] https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/swearing

Comment: @RubioRic As I concluded, *Half the words are....* whatever their intent.

Comment: More info about this subject here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27955/what-are-the-rules-about-using-half-of-with-plural-nouns and here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77466/was-or-were-for-half-a-dozen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fraction matches the whole in number. A fraction of a singular or non-countable whole is expressed as a singular quantity. One third of the loaf has been eaten. Half of the money is missing. A fraction of a plural whole is expressed as a plural quantity. Half of the words you say are profanities. One third of the cars were red. This is true even if the fractional quantity might be equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer indicates, you should use a plural.

However, I need to point out that the sentence as given is semantically nonsensical.

This is grammatical:

> Half of the words that come out of your mouth are swearing.

However (technically), it is also meaningless because *swearing* (in that context) is a verb and words don't swear.

To have meaning, it should be rephrased. For example:

> Half of the words that come out of your mouth are **swear words**.
>   Half of the words that come out of your mouth are **examples of swearing.**